# Subfloat: How to align two images with different width to same height?

Tags: graphics, subfloats, height, subfig

Assumed we have two images with different widths. Now we want to align them next to each other, but with same height.

---

**Minimum working example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Picture A]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
        \subfloat[Picture B]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
        \captionsetup{justification=justified,margin=1cm}
        \caption{Comparison of steady state results (a)~x method (b)~y method}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

The upper MWE is working completely fine as long as both images have the same width and same height.

However, in my case I have two images with same height but different width. How can I declare that both images should adopt the same height while adjusting their necessary width by themselves?

In the past I played around with things like `[width=0.457585\linewidth]` until I scaled them up to (more or less) similar heights what is a annoying approach.

I guess there is some better option available to do so?

Comment: Have you tried `\includegraphics[height = ...]{...}`?

Comment: @zetaeffe: Pleaes post this as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graphicx` package allows you also to set the height of the image (among many other parameters). Here there's a list of some of the possibile parameters (from the package documentation):

[image]

In your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Picture A]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}\quad
        \subfloat[Picture B]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}}\\
        \captionsetup{justification=justified,margin=1cm}
        \caption{Comparison of steady state results (a)~x method (b)~y method}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```